# ASP.NET Security Roles AND Permissions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm comfortable with the ASP.NET security model whereby one can allow/deny access to users in the web.config based on what roles they are in e.g.

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles = "Admin" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

However what I want to do is give the admin user a set of permissions which can then be checked e.g. an Admin user with permissions like "can print documents", "can delete document"

Is this sort of thing possible out of the box or would I need to go down a custom route?

Answer (score 4):

You can use Azman as described in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998336.aspx).

But there are a number of things I don't like about Azman, so I rolled my own as a complement to the RoleProvider (additional tables, APIs and admin tools that manage the mapping of permissions to roles).

My custom implementation is very simple:

- M-N relationship between roles and permissions.
- An API "HasPermission" that tests if a given principal has a given permission.  This simply iterates through all roles and checks if the role has the given permission.  The mapping permission-roles is cached using the ASP.NET cache for performance reasons.

Comment: Looking to perhaps go down this route myself, got a blog post on your implementation? :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not there out of the box; but if you wanted to be more granular, why not have granular roles like "CanPrint", "CanDelete" rather than wider ones like "Admin"?

If they want a container type scenario as you indicate in your comments you could setup a custom IPrincipal - where, after authentication, and with each new request you look at the user's role membership ("Admin", "Public" etc.) and then override IsInRole on your IPrincipal. You can find an example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/AspNetCustomAuth.aspx)

Comment: I thought of this but the system I'm working on will have a lot of users so the client is keen to be able to set up predefined groups (e.g. the roles) rather than having to set individual permissions for groups of users at a time.

Answer (score 1):

i found [this](http://www.jacopretorius.net/2010/01/permission-based-access-in-asp-net-mvc.html) article that gives a nice example

```
[Flags]
public enum Permissions
{
View                 = (1 << 0),
Add                  = (1 << 1),
Edit                 = (1 << 2),
Delete               = (1 << 3),
Admin                = (View | Add | Edit | Delete)
}

public ActionResult Authenticate(string username, string password)
{
var user = authenticationService.Authenticate(username, password);
Session["User"] = user;

return RedirectToAction("Somewhere", "Else");  
}

public class PermissionsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
private readonly Permissions required;

public PermissionsAttribute(Permissions required)
{
    this.required = required;
}

public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var user = filterContext.HttpContext.Session.GetUser();
    if (user == null)
    {
        //send them off to the login page
        var url = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
        var loginUrl = url.Content("~/Home/Login");
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(loginUrl, true);   
    }
    else
    {
        if (!user.HasPermissions(required))
        {
            throw new AuthenticationException("You do not have the necessary permission to perform this action");
        }
    }
}
}

[Permissions(Permissions.View)]
public ActionResult Index()
{

// ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could return PERMISSIONS instead of the ROLES in your RoleProvider.

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username) {
   return GetGrantedPermissions(userName);
}
```

Then create your admin pages to add {granted/denied} permissions to roles and of course users to roles.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it's possible. Create the roles you want, add the users to the roles, and then just check User.IsInRole in your code where you perform the action that requires that role.

Take a look at the Roles and MemberShip classes in System.Web.Security

Comment: Yes I am familiar with these. However what I am wanting to do is for each role have several permissions associated with that role