# ASP.NET Security: single entry of role names

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ldap, authorization

We're building an ASP.NET app, and have a requirement to use the corporate LDAP system (Siteminder) for authentication (upside: no login dialogs).  Roles are created in the LDAP tool, and users are assigned to the roles by userland managers (read: the structure has to be easily understood).  Currently, all apps that use the system use a dual-entry process whereby the roles identified in the app are hand-entered into the LDAP system and users are assigned, then app functions are assigned to their role mirrors in an app-based control panel.  This works, but it bothers me that dual-entry is required.

What I would like to achieve is something where the app queries the LDAP system to get a list of roles that are assigned to the app (which is identified in the LDAP system) and populate the role:function control panel with them.  This part seems really straightforward.  However, I lose clarity when it comes to figuring out what to put in the Authorize attribute:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Moderator")]
```

would become... what?

```
[Authorize(LoadedRoles(r => r.FindAll("some expression that describes the roles that have a particular permission")))]
```

I'm seriously into blue sky territory here.  I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862904/asp-net-security-roles-and-permissions), and liked - from an architectural standpoint - the answer that suggested making the permissions the roles.  But that might not be acceptable to the userland managers that needed to manage users.  On the other hand, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828444/non-string-role-names-in-asp-net-mvc) turns things into non-string resources, but I can't conceive of how to translate that into "roles that have this sort of function included".

Any suggestions?

**Update:**

Based on the advice of @venerik below, I've made some progress.  For the time being, I'm encapsulating everything in the `[AuthorizeFunctionAttribute]`, and will farm the individual pieces out where they belong later.  To that end, I created three variables:

```
    private IList<KeyValuePair<long, string>> Roles;
    private IList<KeyValuePair<long, string>> Functions;
    private IList<RoleFunction> RoleFunctions;
```

...then put static data in them:

```
Roles = new ICollection<KeyValuePair<long, string>>();
Roles.Add(KeyValuePair<long, string>(1, "Basic User"));
Roles.Add(KeyValuePair<long, string>(2, "Administrator"));

Functions = new ICollection<KeyValuePair<long, string>>();
Functions.Add(KeyValuePair<long,string>(1,"List Things"));
Functions.Add(KeyValuePair<long,string>(2,"Add Or Edit Things"));
Functions.Add(KeyValuePair<long,string>(3,"Delete Things"));
```

...and finally bound them together (in a complicated manner that lays the groundwork for the future):

```
RoleFunctions = new IList<RoleFunction>();
RoleFunctions.Add(
   new RoleFunction 
   { 
      RoleId = Roles.Where( r => r.Value == "Basic User").FirstOrDefault().Key, 
      FunctionId = Functions.Where( f => f.Value == "List Things" ).FirstOrDefault().Key,
      isAuthorized = true
   },
   new RoleFunction 
   { 
      RoleId = Roles.Where( r => r.Value == "Administrator").FirstOrDefault().Key, 
      FunctionId = Functions.Where( f => f.Value == "Add or Edit Things" ).FirstOrDefault().Key,
      isAuthorized = true
   },
   // More binding...
);
```

I feel good about this so far.  So I went researching [AuthorizeCore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460355(v=vs.100).aspx) to see what I needed to do there.  However, per the comment at the bottom of the page, it's not very helpful.  I more or less get that at the end, the method needs to return a `bool` value.  And I get that I need to check that one of the `User.Roles` array fits the permission that's passed in through `[AuthorizeFunction("List Things")]`.

**Update (again):**

I've got the following code, which seems like it will do what I need (one method needs fleshing out):

```
/// <summary>An authorization attribute that takes "function name" as a parameter
/// and checks to see if the logged-in user is authorized to use that function.
/// </summary>
public class AuthorizeFunctionAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute 
{
    private IList<KeyValuePair<long, string>> Roles;
    private IList<KeyValuePair<long, string>> Functions;
    private IList<RoleFunction> RoleFunctions;

    public string Function { get; private set; }

    public AuthorizeFunctionAttribute(string FunctionName)
    {
        Function = FunctionName;
        Roles = SetApplicationRoles();
        Functions = SetApplicationFunctions();
        RoleFunctions = SetRoleFunctions();
    }

    protected virtual bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        bool userIsAuthorized = false;
        foreach (string ur in GetUserRoles(httpContext.Current.Request.Headers["SM_USER"]))
        {
            long roleId = Roles.Where( sr => sr.Value == ur )
                .First().Key;
            long functionId = Functions.Where( sf => sf.Value == Function )
                .First().Key;
            // If any role is authorized for this function, set userIsAuthorized to true.
            // DO NOT set userIsAuthorized to false within this loop.
            if (RoleFunctions.Where(rf => rf.RoleId == roleId && rf.FunctionId == functionId)
                .First().isAuthorized) 
            { 
                userIsAuthorized = true; 
            }
        }
        return userIsAuthorized;
    }
```

Previously I didn't know enough about the underlying bits of creating a custom attribute to get out of my own way.  However, [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84c42s56(v=vs.110).aspx) told me what should have been obvious to me in the beginning: build it yourself.  So, once I get the `GetUserRoles()` method put together, I should be underway.

Comment: Attributes require compile-time constants as arguments, so that won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve this using a custom `AuthorizeAttribute`. In a project I worked close to they used that to access Active Directory (as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32871893/can-user-authorization-be-set-on-a-per-controller-basis-in-web-config-cannot-u/32873482#32873482)).

In your case it would look something like:

```
public class AuthorizeWithLDAPAttribute(string functionName) : AuthorizeAttribute 
{
    protected virtual bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
         // check LDAP to verify that user has 
         // a role that's linked to `functionName`
    }
}
```

Next you can use this attribute on your controllers and/or methods:

```
[AuthorizeWithLDAP("functionName1")]
public class BlogController : Controller
{
    ....
    [AuthorizeWithLDAP("functionName2")]
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
         return View();
    }
}
```

The controller is now only accessible to users whose role are linked to `functionName1` and the method is only accessible to users whose role are linked to `functionName1` and `functionName2`

Comment: In this case, is "theController" the name of a role?  What I'm trying to get at is having some way for the names of the roles to be unknown to the application at startup.  So far, I can't find a way around it.

Comment: Oh, never mind.  Three readings later, I'm starting to get it.

Comment: I'm sorry it wasn't clear. Although you figured it out I updated the question anyway.